# How to trigger an action in a Vue.js frontend by a post request

Tags: docker, vue.js, server, request

I have a Vue.js frontend, which runs on an nginx-server. Those are running in a docker container, which is connected to a docker network. I now want to make a post-request from a python script, which triggers an action in the Vue frontend - just some function. The script runs in another docker container, which is connected to the same network.

My first try was to add the following to to the `created` method of my vue view:

```
const self = this;
this.server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/io' && req.method === 'POST') {
    //my action
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Received POST request on /io');
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Page not found');
  }
});
```

This did not work, I could not send a request there. Upon further research I have read, that you may use websockets and or a small backend server to accomplish what I want, as frontends are not capable of this.

So my question is, how can I configure such socket and or server to receive the post request and pass it on to the frontend application and then alter my frontend code to receive the request?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the action you want to trigger from some other script? if your frontend is just a static site why? if you have a backend API you want to trigger then do the API request to that directly

Comment: Currently in the frontend a button is used, to navigate to another site. I want a physical button connected to the host device to do this action. For this reason, I implemented a python script, which polls for a triggering of the button. It then sends a post request, which I want to intercept with in my frontend to make the site-change. Therefore my frontend is not just a static site and I need to access directly.

Comment: do you use server-side rendering in the frontend?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No, I don't.

Comment: Your python script won't render the vue app unless it's opening a headless browser to execute the js that code your spa app is. Your need to rethink it, if it were SSR it would be possible

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't think I understand. The python script is just making a http request, but it could come from another source as well. My goal is to have the frontend react on such a request by triggering a frontend action.

Comment: research the difference [*](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%27s%20the%20difference%20between%20ssr%20and%20spa) the source and DOM of your app is not invoked or rendered serverside but in the browser, so a simple HTTP request, using wget/curl/http libs etc without a js engine wont run your app so methods are impossible to run, your need to use a browser like https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/ , whilst if it were SSR, like in nuxt you can run stuff in the server process with full access to servers req object before anything renders so you can then render what you want

Comment: @LawrenceCherone But the the app is already fully loaded and working, running on an nginx server. I can run the required methods by means of actions of the frontend (e.g. pressing a button), but I also want to be able to trigger it if I receive a request.